# What is the probability that the socks are paired?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $2N$ boxes with box number $\{1,2,\ldots,2N\}$. Every even number box contains $K$ left socks $\{A_1,A_2, \ldots, A_K\}$, and every odd number box contains $K$ right socks $\{B_1,B_2, \ldots, B_K\}$.

Note that these $K$ pairs of socks are different, and $A_k$ is paired with $B_k, \forall k$.
For each sock type, there are $N$ copies in $N$ boxes. For example, there are $N$ socks ${A_1}$ contained in $\{2,4,\ldots,2N\}$ boxes, and each of them can be paired with $B_1$.

Then, if we randomly select one sock from each  box, what is the probability that all the $2N$ socks are all paired?

Comment: Wait, how many socks are there in total? $2NK$? Are there $2K$ sock types, $N$ of each?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the following more mathematical one: Draw $N$ samples (with replacement) from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and count the occurrences. Now do the same thing a second time. What is the probability that both times each number from $1$ to $k$ is drawn the same number of times?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are $2K$ sock types, and $N$ of each.

Comment: @ Jeroen van der Meer. I agree with your comment that these two problems are equivalent. When I try to solve this, for small $N$, it is still okay to handle it. But for large $N$, it is hard to find some general law.

Comment: Perhaps you want so say:  "For any integer $k: 1\le k \le n$ then box number $2k$ has contains $k$ left socks (labeled $\{A_1, .... A_k\}$) and the box number $2k-1$ contains $k$ right socks (labeled $\{B_1,..., B_k\}$)"

Comment: "When I try to solve this, for small N, it is still okay to handle it. But for large N, it is hard to find some general law"  Here's a simpler question.   What is the probabality that the one pair of socks you pull from the two boxes with $k$ socks are a match? Now here are two more questions.  1) Will a pair of socks chosen in one pair of boxes have any effect whatsoever on a pair of socks chosen from another pair of boxes (i.e. are the events (in)dependent) and 2) what is the rule of probability of multiple independent events occurring?

Comment: If the probability of event $M$ occuring is $\frac 13$ and if the probability of even $N$ occuring is $\frac 15$ and the probability of event $P$ is $\frac 8{17}$ what is the probability of all three events occuring (assuming the events are independent .... the one event occuring or not occuring has no effect on the likelihood of the others occuring or not occuring)?

Comment: @fleablood Perhaps you want so say: "For any integer k:1≤k≤n then box number 2k has contains k left socks (labeled {A1,....Ak}) and the box number 2k−1 contains k right socks (labeled {B1,...,Bk})". Here, I mean the box index and the sock index are different. For example, if $N=2$, then, box $2$ and box $4$ contains the same socks, i.e., $\{ A_1, A_2,\ldots, A_K\}$.

Comment: I figured such from context.  Notation wise you should use double indexing.   $A_{5_3}$ would be the third left sock in the fifth pair of boxes.  Box 1: $B_{1_1}$. Box 2: $A_{1_1}$. Box 3: $B_{2_1},B_{2_2}$ Box 4: $A_{2_1}, A_{2_2}$.  Box 5: $B_{3_1},B_{3_2},B_{3_3}$ and so on.... but don't get bogged down in notation.  It has nothing to do with actually solving the problem.

Comment: @fleablood however, the true answer involves Bessel functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you pick all the left socks first and obtain $n_i$ socks of type $A_i$. There are $\binom N{n_1,\dots,n_K}$ ways you could have obtained that sample and the same number of ways to pick the matching sample from the right socks, so the probability's numerator is
$$f(N,K)=\sum_{n_1+\cdots+n_K=N}\binom N{n_1,\dots,n_K}^2$$
which is [OEIS A287316](https://oeis.org/A287316), and the denominator is clearly $K^{2N}$.

The numerator has the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f(n,k)}{n!^2}x^n=I_0^k(2\sqrt x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. I can't  understand the provided link  OEIS A287316. Does it just provide the table of $f(N,K)$?

Comment: @Harry $\text{Yes.}$